# Display grid isn't aligning columns evenly as it should

Tags: css, css-grid

For some odd reason, whenever I use "Display: Grid;", the columns are never aligned evenly.

All "Individual-stories" class sections have the same exact styling so that isn't the issue.

HTML:

```
 <section class="features">

      <div class="individual-features">
        <img src="assets/features/desktop/responsive.svg" alt="">
        <h3>100% Responsive</h3>
        <p>No matter which the device you’re on, our site is fully responsive and stories look beautiful on any screen.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="individual-features">
        <img src="assets/features/desktop/no-limit.svg" alt="">
        <h3>No Photo Upload Limit</h3>
        <p>Our tool has no limits on uploads or bandwidth. Freely upload in bulk and share all of your stories in one go.</p>
      </div>
      

      <div class="individual-features">
        <img src="assets/features/desktop/embed.svg" alt="">
        <h3>Available to Embed</h3>
        <p>Embed Tweets, Facebook posts, Instagram media, Vimeo or YouTube videos, Google Maps, and more. </p>
      </div>

    </section>
```

The css styling is;

```
.features{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 2em;
    padding: 10.31em;
    text-align: center;
}
.features img{
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.features p{
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Any advise?

Comment: Attach the HTML please, we should be able to at a minimum copy and paste your code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This all seems to space evenly on my end. The only reason this does not space evenly when the viewport is smaller is because there is not ample space to fit your grid elements, so you are experiencing what is known as a grid blowout. This article helped me overcome this issue: [Preventing a Grid Blowout](https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/)

You'll need to expand the space available by decreasing the number of columns, by decreasing the padding which squishes these items, or by another means.

```css
.features{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 2em;
    padding: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
.features img{
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.features p{
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section class="features">

      <div class="individual-features">
        <img src="assets/features/desktop/responsive.svg" alt="">
        <h3>100% Responsive</h3>
        <p>No matter which the device you’re on, our site is fully responsive and stories look beautiful on any screen.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="individual-features">
        <img src="assets/features/desktop/no-limit.svg" alt="">
        <h3>No Photo Upload Limit</h3>
        <p>Our tool has no limits on uploads or bandwidth. Freely upload in bulk and share all of your stories in one go.</p>
      </div>
      

      <div class="individual-features">
        <img src="assets/features/desktop/embed.svg" alt="">
        <h3>Available to Embed</h3>
        <p>Embed Tweets, Facebook posts, Instagram media, Vimeo or YouTube videos, Google Maps, and more. </p>
      </div>

    </section>
```